# Cross-Origin Request Blocked on localhost for Express Server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, server, cors

I'm developing a web application where the frontend is hosted on https://admin.athletept.de and the backend is running on http://localhost:8080. I'm trying to make a request from the frontend to the backend, but I'm getting a CORS error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/auth/login. (Reason: CORS request failed). Status code: (null).
```

Here's how I've set up CORS on my Express server:

```
const server = express();

server.use(cors({
  origin: "https://admin.athletept.de",
  credentials: true,
}));

server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(cookieParser());
```

I've also tried disabling the helmet middleware, which didn't resolve the issue. The Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is missing in the server's responses, and I'm not sure why.

Does anyone know what could be causing this issue and how to fix it?

Comment: Might be a problem of mixed content. Ie your frontend is secured via https, but your backend is http only. Most browsers don't allow this nowadays

Comment: so what if i issue a https certificat for my backend? But how can i manage this with localhost because frontend and backend are sitting both on the same server.

Comment: *"frontend and backend are sitting both on the same server*"? How is `localhost` on the same server as  `https://admin.athletept.de`? `localhost` always points to the machine where the code is executed. Ie in case of your frontend, it points to the very machine you are sitting in front of (unless you are remotely connected to that other server and started your browser from there)

Comment: My frontend is a website thats hosted on the same server as the backend.

Comment: If that's the case, you must not use `http://localhost` as url to the backend because that points to your local machine where your browser is running. But you have to use an url that points to the actual server where the backend is running. And if the serverprocess you showed above also serves the frontend-files, you don't even need CORS, because that's not a Cross Origin situation. Then you don't even need the host part in your backend calls, but just do `fetch("/api/endpoint", ...)`

Comment: @LetsGhost Please post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for your server code.

Comment: @derpirscher My Express server doesnt serve the frontend, the frontend is a statick html that gets served from nginx and my backend is running in a docker container

Comment: Your infrastructure setup is really unclear. First you say frontend and backend are on the same server. Now one of them is in a docker container? Where is that docker container running? On your local machine or on the same machine from where the frontend is served? Is that backend reachable from for instance postman?

Comment: I am sorry i am very bad at explaining. I have an ubuntu server where i run a docker container that servers as my backend( its an nodejs express web server). Then i have a static HTML file that gets served from nginx on a domain, all on the same ubuntu server. The HTML makes a fetch reuquest to my backend with the localhost:8080 where the backend is running on. The Backend works fine when i reach it with postman, somehow something gets blocked.

Comment: So you have an ubuntu server which is reachable via `https://admin.athletept.de`. On this ubuntu server there is an nginx which serves your frontend and a docker container which serves your backend. Your browser and postman are running on the same server? Or on your local machine? If the latter, you must not use `localhost` to connect to the backend but a URL that points to your server. Because in a browser running on your local machine, localhost points to the local machine and not any remote server ... I don't know how to make that any clearer after explaining it three times ...

Comment: Okay i think i got it now. The error I am getting now is 
```
XHROPTIONS
https://backend.athletept.de/auth/login
CORS Missing Allow Origin

Quellübergreifende (Cross-Origin) Anfrage blockiert: Die Gleiche-Quelle-Regel verbietet das Lesen der externen Ressource auf https://backend.athletept.de/auth/login. (Grund: CORS-Kopfzeile 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' fehlt). Statuscode: 502.
```

Comment: It is working now i dont know why. I think the CORS config and preflight was not correct.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
server.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://admin.athletept.de');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();
});
```

Hope this help!

Comment: I alreday done that, I think cors is configured perfectly.

Comment: Can you show me how your frontend request looks like?  If anything, try including in your request options like {credentials: 'include'} or {withCredentials: true}

Comment: A request in my frontend would look something like this 
`try {
  const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/auth/login", { email: eml.value, password: pas.value });
  if (response.data.success) {
    auth.login(response.data.userId);
    router.push({ name: "Dashboard" });
  } else {
    console.log("Login failed");
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.log("Request error");
}
`

Comment: Did you try putting {withCrentials: true} option to it on the frontend? Put it in your const response:


const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/auth/login", {
    email: eml.value,
    password: pas.value
  }, {
    withCredentials: true // Add this option
  });

see if that works first?

Comment: saddly didn´t worked